# iOS 9 WKWebView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge on OAuth 2 flow

Tags: ios, oauth

I have been happily using WKWebView to handle the Instagram OAuth implicit flow in iOS 8.x. However, in iOS 9, my WKWebView navigationDelegate is receiving a 'didReciveAuthenticationChallenge' call and I don't know how to handle it.

I've tried calling the completionHandler with all 4 of the NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition types (all with an NSURLCredential of nil) and none of them work. Navigation just ends.

In iOS 8, I did not receive this call and navigation proceeded to the Instagram login page as expected.

Has anyone else found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved this by setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in plist.info. Not a safe fix, but since (for the time being) the app controls the two very well known web sites it visits, it should be safe enough. :-)